# Group policy configuration error - Server Essentials 2012

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I am trying to use the "Implement Group Policy" wizard in Windows Server 2012 Essentials.

I have a domain created and a computer included in that domain. When I choose to "Implement Group Policy" I select "all" in the Enable Folder Redirection Group Policy and also select "Windows Update", "Windows Defender" and "Network Firewall".

I finish the wizard and get the error

> ### Group Policy Configuration Did Not Succeed
>
> Group policy configuration encountered an error. Restart the wizard
>   and try again.

The user's machine is Windows 8 Pro. I have checked the event logs and for .log files and cannot find anything that helps.

I have also tried selecting no folders to redirect and different combinations of the "Security Policy Settings"

Can anyone here offer some guidance as to why this is failing.

Thanks

Pat

Answer (score 0):

Check the Event logs then take a look at the Group Policy Management console and see if the wizard actually made any changes. You may need to make the changes manually. (Run gpmc.msc)

Take a look at [Technet Group Policy Management Console](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725752.aspx) and then [Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786749%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more info. Evidently there's now a group policy log in the gpmc which should give you more information.